# Fetching the first name and deleting the rest in a string

Tags: ruby, string, gsub

I am crawling a couple of names of a site and I only need a there first name. 
How do I remove everything in a string and just output the first name: `Veronica`

This what I doing right know, remember that are other names.

```
name = "Name: Veronica Ljunglöf"
name.gsub!("Name: ", '')
```

Comment: How do you define a *first name*? What about people with multiple names, what about people without a first name? I advise to read [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: @spikermann, yes, like ["Cher"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cher), and [“Barnaby Marmaduke Aloysius Benjy Cobweb Dartagnan Egbert Felix Gaspar Humbert Ignatius Jayden Kasper Leroy Maximilian Neddy Obiajulu Pepin Quilliam Rosencrantz Sexton Teddy Upwood Vivatma Wayland Xylon Yardley Zachary Usansky”](http://www.historyrundown.com/top-5-people-with-the-longest-names/).

Comment: As @spickermann pointed out, your code is too naive. Don't assume names fit a first name/last name mold. Many societies use last name/first name, and your code could result in horribly mangled results if you assume it did the right thing. Instead, *ASK* the person what their first and last names are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the format looks consistent, you could do:

```
name = "Name: Veronica Ljunglöf"
=> "Name: Veronica Ljunglöf"
name.split[1]
=> "Veronica"
```

Comment: What if a person have a middle name like: John Sallad Doe?

Comment: Don't forget to use the second argument to `split` to stop splitting after the *n*th part: `name.split(' ', 3)[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular expression:

```
r = /
    :\s+         # match a colon followed by one or more spaces
    \K           # forget everything matched so far
    [[:alpha:]]+ # match one or more letters
    /x           # extended/free-spacing regex definition mode

'name = "Name: Veronica Lodge"'[r]
  #=> "Veronica"<sup>1</sup>
```

<sub><sup>[That's the one Archie is looking at](http://www.thestar.com/content/dam/thestar/entertainment/2009/05/27/archie_spurns_betty_to_wed_veronica/archie_betty_andveronica.jpeg.size.xxlarge.letterbox.jpeg).</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

You can do ...

```
name.gsub("Name: ", "").split.first
```

Comment: @Anthony, well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative that is more verbose, but also more general. You can match multiple patterns, and could adapt it to first and last names (for example).

```
"Name: Veronica Ljunglöf".match(/Name: (\w*) \w*/)  #=> #<MatchData "Name: Veronica Ljunglöf" 1:"Veronica">
```

Access "Veronica" with MatchData#captures

```
"Name: Veronica Ljunglöf".match(/Name: (\w*) \w*/).captures #=> ["Veronica"]
```

Take the first (and only) capture

```
"Name: Veronica Ljunglöf".match(/Name: (\w*) \w*/).captures.first #=> "Veronica"
```